# install `find` program for android emulator

Tags: android, linux

I've tried running simple linux related command like `find` but there's no such command on linux OS that is supplied with AVD. I then wanted to check linux distro to install that program but it showed something I don't know `nnk@nnk.mtv.corp.google.com` here:

```
Linux version 3.4.0+ (nnk@nnk.mtv.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 P
REEMPT Wed Jul 10 09:55:37 PDT 2013
```

What is this linux distribution and how can I install programs on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested on [installing busybox for android](http://dazzle1.typepad.com/blog/2010/09/reference-howto-how-to-install-busybox.html), in the device [or in the emulator](https://allencch.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/learn-to-root-android-using-emulator/) it has alot of linux commands such as "find". But the procedure may require rooting the emulator/device.

Comment: thanks, are AVDs by default not rooted? And do you know which linux distro is used by AVDs?

Comment: I haven't work on android since a long time, but as far as I know, AVD are not rooted by default, you don't need to root your avd to install busybox, howerver you will need to start the emulator by providing extra partition size to /system (emulator -avd MyAndroid -partition-size 128 -no-snapshot-load), then remount the /system with read-write (adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system), then push busybox to avd (adb push busybox /system/xbin/), then give it permissions (adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/busybox). That's it.

Comment: I'm not sure, to use "find" by busybox, you will have to run "find" simply, or "busybox find", in this case, may be (ln -s /system/xbin/busybox sh) will do the trick (if avd has the "ln" command). Hope this works.